# Spring Security Concurrent Session Control

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to restrict user session to one at a time from anywhere. But it doesn't work. When I try to access the application with the same user on two navigator, I have access.
I noticed that when a user connects to the application on two different machines to start printing two different reports, there is an print that comes out instead of the other.
Thanks for help.

My Security config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /*@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;*/

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration( 
            @Qualifier("customAccessDeneiedHandler")AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
            @Qualifier("customSuccessHandler")AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler,
            @Qualifier("customAuthenticationFailureHandler")AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler,
            @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.accessDeniedHandler = accessDeniedHandler;
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.configure(auth);

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)   //auth.userDetailsService(utilisateurDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    //Authorization
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ajouterassure", "/ajouterattributaire", "/ajouterbeneficiaire", "/ajouterpiecejustificative",
                             "/creerbordereauemission", "/creerbehorscoordination", "/creerbordereaupaie", "/ajouteravance", 
                             "/creerbeavanceannuelle")
                            .hasAnyRole("DGA", "DGAA", "DR", "DRA", "CC", "CCA", "CI", "AS", "GUICHET", "CE", "CAP", "ADMIN") //.hasRole("ADMIN")

                .antMatchers("/ajoutercentre", "/ajouteretablissementpaie", "/ajoutertypepj", "/ajoutertypedette",
                             "/ajoutersexe", "/ajoutersituationbeneficiaire", "/ajoutercategoriebeneficiaire", 
                             "/ajoutercategorieattributaire", "/ajouterrevalorisation").hasAnyRole("DGA", "ADMIN")  //hasAnyRole("CAP", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/payerdecompte").hasAnyRole("CAISSIER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/ajouterutilisateur").hasAnyRole("CI", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                //.httpBasic()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                //.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("identifiant")
                .passwordParameter("mot_de_passe")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                //.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()            //Session controle concurence access
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

        //Session controle concurence access
        //http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/resources/templates/errors/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/var/signatures/**");
        //web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }



 @Bean(name = "sessionRegistry")
 public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
     return new SessionRegistryImpl();
 }

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `.maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)` ?

Comment: I tried .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) as you said, it's work fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Just in case someone finds it useful.]*

Always add hashcode and equals methods in custom UserDetails class along with the below config in the spring security configuration class for the concurrent sessions to work.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
{
    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() 
{
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add `.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)` after `maximumSessions(1)` and it stop logging in from other places util session expires here. So your configure method should look like this :-

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ajouterassure", "/ajouterattributaire", "/ajouterbeneficiaire", "/ajouterpiecejustificative",
                         "/creerbordereauemission", "/creerbehorscoordination", "/creerbordereaupaie", "/ajouteravance", 
                         "/creerbeavanceannuelle")
                        .hasAnyRole("DGA", "DGAA", "DR", "DRA", "CC", "CCA", "CI", "AS", "GUICHET", "CE", "CAP", "ADMIN") //.hasRole("ADMIN")

            .antMatchers("/ajoutercentre", "/ajouteretablissementpaie", "/ajoutertypepj", "/ajoutertypedette",
                         "/ajoutersexe", "/ajoutersituationbeneficiaire", "/ajoutercategoriebeneficiaire", 
                         "/ajoutercategorieattributaire", "/ajouterrevalorisation").hasAnyRole("DGA", "ADMIN")  //hasAnyRole("CAP", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/payerdecompte").hasAnyRole("CAISSIER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/ajouterutilisateur").hasAnyRole("CI", "ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //.httpBasic()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("identifiant")
            .passwordParameter("mot_de_passe")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            //.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()            //Session controle concurence access
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

    //Session controle concurence access
    //http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
}
```